# Dynamic type enumerable and struct enumerable casting

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to cast an enumerable of struct into an enumerable of dynamic type:

```
    var guidList = new List<Guid>
    {
        new Guid("35138521-7424-49EE-9D4B-1CE15D7281BE"),
        new Guid("4C8555A5-2D51-426B-8E3A-1E990DA4C528")
    };

    // This fails
    var castedGuidList = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)guidList;
```

Code will compile but I will get the error:

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Guid]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[System.Object]'."

This examples shows using Guid, but this happens using **any struct type**. How can I define a generic enumerable of structs if I cant use dynamic type?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a generic enumerable of structs"? Normally "generic" in that context refers to, well, generics, but you don't seem to be using generics.

Comment: I'm curious why you would even want to do this, it's highly unusual. Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies.

Comment: `var castedGuidList = guidList.Cast<dynamic>();`

Comment: At the point where I do the casting, I am only getting a dynamic, so I need to cast it to be able to work with it as a list/enumerable again. The list could be of any type, the example shows a list of Guid, but it could be any type of list, a list containg objects, integers, strings or structs. For objects, integers and strings this works fine. With a list of structs it fails.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean. If you want to work with a list of any type, then it's likely generics would be a better way to go. Without seeing your code, it's impossible to tell, but using dynamic is almost certainly not the way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
var guidList = new List<Guid>
    {
        new Guid("35138521-7424-49EE-9D4B-1CE15D7281BE"),
        new Guid("4C8555A5-2D51-426B-8E3A-1E990DA4C528")
    };

//This works
var castedGuidList =guidList.Cast<dynamic>().ToList();
```

Comment: The `ToList` isn't necessary (given the OP wants an `IEnumerable`).

Comment: Also, code only answers don't tend to get upvotes. Explain **why** this works, while the OP's code doesn't.

Comment: Also, while this technically gives OP what they want, I personally wouldn't have answered it because it's almost certainly a bad thing to do.